# Why my SimpleDateFormat is the same after parsing of concatenated string?

Tags: java, datetime, simpledateformat, date-format

I have very strange situation. My date is not changing after I am using parse() method from SimpleDateFormat. I tried to search on another questions on the site but without any success. This is my code:

```
String CALENDAR_NO_TIMEZONE = "dd-M-yyyy hh:mm:ss a";
String CALENDAR_FORMAT = "dd-M-yyyy hh:mm:ss a Z";

String dateValue = new SimpleDateFormat(CALENDAR_NO_TIMEZONE).format(scheduledDate);
Date scheduledDate = new SimpleDateFormat(CALENDAR_FORMAT, Locale.US).parse(dateValue + " " + timeZoneAbbr);
```

For example my value for dateValue is "17-2-2021 12:15:00 AM", for timeZoneAbbr is "ACT" and for scheduledDate is "Wed Feb 17 0:15:00 CET 2021" before parsing, but also after parsing everything is the same, like this parse is not working. So where I am wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For me, your code throws a `ParseException`... which makes sense, as `ATC` is not a known Timezone for Java. When I replace that with `UTC`, then the `scheduledDate` has properly changed.

Comment: @MonsterDruide1sorry my bad spelling, timezone is "ACT" (Australian Time Zone), please check with that value and you should get the same as I...

Comment: Do you live in that timezone? Java will automatically convert any Date to your local date, if given the origin timezone. For me, using the `ACT` timezone results in ~4 AM, whereas the original date is ~22 PM.

Comment: Oh, so my parsing is working well, thank you for clarification...

Comment: Three (and four and five) letter time zone abbreviations are often ambiguous. ACT may be for Acre Time (in South America) or Australian Central Time.

Comment: You are using `scheduledDate` before declaring it? Could you [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), please?

Comment: Does ACT as an Australian time zone make any sense here? Doesn’t Central/Southern Australia use summer time (daylight saving time, ACDT, CDT or CDST) on 17 February?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `ZonedDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).